# Ground state conformation of dimethyl disulfide

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

What is the ground state conformation of dimethyl disulfide ?

The two which seem reasonable to me are trans to avoid methyl-methyl gauche interactions or gauche due to sulfur donation into the S-Me sigma antibonding orbital.

I found a discussion in [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100547a013) but it doesn't seem to really answer the question definitely.

Comment: Your reference says that the $\ce{C-S-S-C}$ dihedral angle is close to 90°, what additional information are you looking for?